# How to change number of Google search results returned

Tags: firefox, google-search

Google search engine in Firefox returns 10 results per page. Is there a way to change it (adding &num=30 in address bar doesn't count)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the Google homepage in the top right, go to **Settings -> Search Settings** (or just **Search Settings** if you aren't logged in). Scroll down to **Number of results per page** and change it in the dropdown box.

[image]

You should be able to choose from 10,20,30,50 or 100.

Comment: This options is no longer available (tested on v66.0).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do sounds like change the URL string that firefox uses when searching from the keyword search in the upper right hand.

1. Open "about:config" (without quotes) in the address bar.
2. click "I'll be careful" button
3. do a search for "keyword.URL"
4. you can then double click and change the URL to the one you would like to use.

If you mess it up just right click on the string and reset it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the number of results by:

1. Going to `about:config` in the address bar
2. Accept the warning message
3. Find the `browser.urlbar.maxRichResults` option
4. The default is 10, you can modify to any integer

[image: Firefox about:config settings]

Tested in Firefox 66.0.